# How to send a lot of different data back through AJAX

Tags: php, jquery, ajax

I have a JavaScript function that sends data to my PHP script via `$.ajax`. My PHP script returns a number of things that I use to create a Jquery UI dialog box, such as the title of the box and its contents (html).

I am returning the bits of data (such as the dialog title and body) in one long string, with each segment separated by `::`, then using:

```
myStuff = data.split('::') ;
```

Finally, I use `myStuff[n]` for the first part I want to use.

I would like to know if you guys know a better way of doing this? Better as in faster/less code, more secure etc.

Comment: I guess you want `JSON` in your response..

Comment: https://developer.mozilla.org/en/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/JSON  http://www.php.net/manual/en/ref.json.php

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I believe that using a [JSON](http://www.json.org/) object would be more appropriate. It would make the code more readable and would avoid the parsing, as Javascript can natively parse JSON objects:

```
var title = myObj.title;
```

There are many choices for creating JSON objects in PHP to chose from.

Answer (score 5):

Your best option is [Json](http://www.w3schools.com/json/default.asp).

PHP has 2 great functions for dealing with Json, [json_decode](http://php.net/manual/en/function.json-decode.php) and [json_encode](http://php.net/manual/en/function.json-encode.php)